# Proof involving gradient vector and orthonormal system (Without using basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Is it possible to prove the result below **without** using the fact that $\mathbf{u_1, u_2, u_3}$ are a basis?

**RTP.** If $ f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R $ is differentiable and $\mathbf{u_1, u_2, u_3} \in \mathbb R^3$ is an orthonormal system, prove that

$$(\mathbf{u}_1\cdot\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))^2+(\mathbf{u}_2\cdot\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))^2+(\mathbf{u}_3\cdot\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))^2=\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\bigg)^2 $$

My attempts:
I've seen in questions that look similar to this we usually take the "dot product" of both sides with one of the orthonormal vectors and take advance of the fact $\mathbf{u_i}\cdot \mathbf{u_j}=0 $ if $i\ne j $.
However in this question I don't imagine something like that would work because both sides are scalar quantities so the dot product wouldn't work.

Something else I was thinking of using was $ (a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2-2(ab+bc+ac) $ but with no success in applying it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't drop that condition.

The statement
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (u_i \cdot v)^2 = \|v\|^2\text{ for all }v\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
is true if and only if the $u_i$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The function $f$ and the derivatives in the statement you're working with are a smokescreen; there's just the gradient vector, which can be anything in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We take its dot products with the $u_i$ squared on the right, and it's norm squared on the left.

What would happen if the $u_i$ were merely an orthonormal system, and not a basis? We would get [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality) instead, replacing the $=$ with a $\le$. A vector $v$ perpendicular to the span of the $u_i$ would have the left side zero and the right side positive.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is a really useful and makes a lot of sense. Thanks as well for referencing the relevant results as well, I will look into them further :)